# Add additional content in extended view in vaadin

Tags: vaadin

If I made navigator and do addview in it:

```
n = new navigator(.....);
```

And make two views where view2 extended view1.

And do another things:

```
n.addView("view1", View1.class);
n.addView("view2", View2.class);
```

How can I add additional components in view2 like labels, tables or vertical Layout etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in Vaadin Book:
https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/advanced.navigator.html
but I also highlight here some code parts:

**Setting Up for Navigation**

```
public class MyUI extends UI {
    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
    // Create a navigator to control the views
    navigator = new Navigator(this, this);

    // Create and register the views
    navigator.addView("", new StartView());
    navigator.addView(MAINVIEW, new MainView());
}
```

**Implementing a View**

"Views can be any objects that implement the View interface."

```
public class StartView extends VerticalLayout implements View {
    public StartView() {
        setSizeFull();

        Button button = new Button("Go to Main View",
                new Button.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
                navigator.navigateTo(MAINVIEW);
            }
        });
        addComponent(button);
        setComponentAlignment(button, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);
    }        

    @Override
    public void enter(ViewChangeEvent event) {
        Notification.show("Welcome to the Animal Farm");
    }
}
```

The code is from Vaadin Book.

Notice that the View is regular class. It has special method `entry()` which is called after each view entry. All components, layouts etc. you could make in class constructor (for instance in example above: `addComponent(button)`).

If you want to navigate to any registered view (registered in means of called method `addView("viewName", ...)` with view name), you can simply call `navigateTo("viewName")`. The navigator you can obtain in two ways:

```
getUI().getNavigator().navigateTo("viewName");
```

or

```
UI.getCurrent().getNavigator().navigateTo("viewName");
```

I hope this is understandable.

**EDIT:**

Consider simple example:

```
public class View1 extends VerticalLayout implements View {
    protected Label hello = new Label("Hello");
    private Button button = new Button("Click me");

    public View1() {
        addComponent(hello);
        addComponent(button);
    }

    public Button getButton() {
        return button;
    }
}

public class View2 extends View1 {
    private Button button2 = new Button("Don't click me");

    public View2() {
        hello.setValue("Hello world");
        getButton().setIcon(...);  
        addComponent(button2);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, now I can't test any code so the code above is only idea.

So is it what you need? Or maybe I misunderstand your problem?

Comment: Yes this is understandable, but I make view2 like extended class of class view1:). I attempt to add on sample label in second view(view2) that it actually extended class off view1. Something like:

public class view2 extend view1{..........}

Comment: Ok. Sorry, but I still think that you can do this in your `view2()` constructor.  But it could be not possible (or very hard) if `view1`  has everything private. But if you follow Vaadin Book example and make `view1` extends a layout (for example `VerticalLayout`), then you could even call `removeAllComponents` in `view2()` constructor or `removeComponent(Component c)`. And you can still make some components of `view1` protected scope.

Comment: Protected scope component  of view1 remain on a view even we do remove(Component c)? Actually I wish to add one or two component in contents on page!

Comment: I added very simple example which illustrate what I talking about.